# Integrate JW Player in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I'm new to angular. I want to know how to integrate JWPlayer in my angular 4 project.I have already imported src of jwplayer.js in .angular-cli.json.
Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

First you have to make it visible in your Angular project by adding a type definition:

```
declare var jwplayer: any;
```

You can add this type definition either in the component ts-file or in the typings.d.ts file.

Then add the div to your component like that:

```
<div id="myDiv">This text will be replaced with a player.</div>
```

Then in the component add the code e.g. in the ngOnInit function:

```
jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
  "file": "http://example.com/myVideo.mp4",
  "image": "http://example.com/myImage.png",
  "height": 360,
  "width": 640
});
```

If the import through angular-cli.json does not work you can also add a script tag to the head area of your index.html and load it there directly.

Comment: Thank you so much brother , it really helped :)

Comment: How did you manage to retrieve jwplayer.key from database dynamically instead of hardcoding?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the @ludwig solution. Here you can [try it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjasxx) on Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjasxx

Comment: How did you manage to import the player js file?
(content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xxxx.js)

Comment: @Enrico I have it in my "index.html" file. Like: 

`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- JwPlayer-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/libs/jwplayer-7.12.3/jwplayer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="1D+blahblah/blahblah=="</script>

</body>
</html>
`

Comment: This example works great. However, jwplayer.key is publicly viewable as its directly added under index.html. Is there any way to programatically recive the same under typescript itself from database?

Comment: I don't understand how this works, I get "ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined" and it's quite logic to get that... how do you have that object reference only from this declaration:

declare var jwplayer:any;